# Не корректно перемещаются строки при перетаскивании технологией drag&drop в QTableView модели QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

Метод нужен для сортировки строк с перетаскиванием на нужную позицию. 
В первые разы метод срабатывает вполне нормально, затем строки сбрасываются по не понятной мне логике в разные места, отличные от место сброса. Иногда строка вообще не перемещается. 
Не могу понять в чем дело, уже отчаялся:(

Код метода:

```
def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, action, dropRow, col, parent):
    dragRow = self.table.currentIndex().row()
    if dropRow == -1:
        return False
    for i in range(dropRow, self.rowCount()):
        if i == dropRow:
            print(i)
            self.setData(self.index(dragRow, 1), dropRow)
            self.setData(self.index(dropRow, 1), dropRow + 1)
        elif i > dropRow:
            if i != dragRow:
                self.setData(self.index(i, 1), i + 1)
    self.table.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(-1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
    self.table.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
    return False
```

---

Вот весь код:

```
import sys, sqlite3, random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql

class createNewTable():
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('TestSQLTable.db')
        self.cursor = self.con.cursor()
    def createTable(self):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE datafiles (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            number INTEGER,
            name TEXT
            )
            """)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

newTable = createNewTable()
newTable.createTable()


class MyModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):


    def __init__(self, table):
        QtSql.QSqlTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.dataChanged.connect(self.submitAll)
        self.table = table


    def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, action, dropRow, col, parent):
        dragRow = self.table.currentIndex().row()
        if dropRow == -1:
            return False
        for i in range(dropRow, self.rowCount()):
            if i == dropRow:
                print(i)
                self.setData(self.index(dragRow, 1), dropRow)
                self.setData(self.index(dropRow, 1), dropRow + 1)
            elif i > dropRow:
                if i != dragRow:
                    self.setData(self.index(i, 1), i + 1)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(-1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.table.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        return False

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

    def flags(self, indexRow):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled


class MyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):

    def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
        if element == self.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop and not option.rect.isNull():
            option_new = QtWidgets.QStyleOption(option)
            option_new.rect.setLeft(0)
            if widget:
                option_new.rect.setRight(widget.width())
            option = option_new
        super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)

class MyTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyle(MyStyle())
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)  # Выделение строки
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)  # разрешаем события перетаскивания для виджета
        self.setDragEnabled(True)  # перетаскивание элементов разрешено;
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)  # позиция возможного сброса элемента будет подсвечена
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)


class Testing(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_add_record = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить запись')
        self.btn_add_record.clicked.connect(self.on_add_record)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.table = MyTableView(self)
        self.model = MyModel(self.table)
        self.model.setTable('datafiles')
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.select()
        # self.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self.updateNumRow)
        self.updateNumRow()

        vbox_main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(vbox_main)
        vbox_main.addWidget(self.btn_add_record)
        vbox_main.addWidget(self.table)
        self.resize(1200, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Drag&Drop Rows in TableView with SqlTableModel')
        self.show()

    def on_add_record(self):
        if self.table.selectionModel().currentIndex().row() == -1:
            self.model.insertRow(0)
        else:
            self.model.insertRow(self.table.selectionModel().currentIndex().row() + 1)

    def updateNumRow(self):
        for i, x in enumerate(range(self.model.rowCount())):
            self.model.setData(self.model.index(i, 1), i)  # + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    database.setDatabaseName(r'TestSQLTable.db')
    database.open()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    test = Testing()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: sorry, вы пробовали запустить пример, который предоставлен как `весь код` ?

Comment: мои извинения, уже поправил

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим, что написано в документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dropMimeData

> bool QAbstractItemModel::dropMimeData(
> const QMimeData *data, 
> Qt::DropAction action, 
> int row, 
> int column, 
> const QModelIndex &parent
> )

Обрабатывает данные, предоставленные операцией перетаскивания, завершившейся заданным действием. 
...

1. Когда строка и столбец равны `-1`, это означает, что 'dropped' данные следует рассматривать как 'dropped' непосредственно на родительском элементе.
   Обычно это означает добавление данных в качестве дочерних элементов родительского элемента.
2. Если строка и столбец `больше или равны нулю`, это означает,
   что `drop` произошло непосредственно перед указанной строкой и столбцом в указанном родительском элементе.

Когда вы при перетаскивание курсор мыши располагаете `на строке`,
мы видим выделение прямоугольника, который обводит строку над которой находится мышка.
Если мы делаем `dropped` получаем описанное в пункте 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вы при перетаскивание курсор мыши располагаете `между строками`,
мы видим выделенную линию, которая находится между строками.
Если мы делаем `dropped` получаем описанное в пункте 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я так понимаю, что вам нужен пункт 2, т.е. курсор мыши располагаете `между строками`.

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql


class createNewTable():
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('TestSQLTable.db')
        self.cursor = self.con.cursor()
    def createTable(self):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE datafiles (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            number INTEGER,
            name TEXT
            )
            """)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f'Error: {ex}')

# выполните один раз при первом запуске приложения
newTable = createNewTable()
newTable.createTable()


class MyModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table):
        QtSql.QSqlTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.dataChanged.connect(self.submitAll)
        self.table = table

    def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, action, dropRow, col, parent):
        print(f'\n dropRow={dropRow}, col={col}')                         # +++
        print(f' dragRow={self.table.currentIndex().row()}')              # +++
        
        dragRow = self.table.currentIndex().row()
        
        if dropRow == -1:
            return False
            
        for i in range(dropRow, self.rowCount()):
            print(f'\n i={i} <---> dropRow={dropRow}')
            if i == dropRow:
                print(f'if {i} == {dropRow}:')
                self.setData(self.index(dragRow, 1), dropRow)
                self.setData(self.index(dropRow, 1), dropRow + 1)
            elif i > dropRow:
                if i != dragRow:
                    self.setData(self.index(i, 1), i + 1)

        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(-1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.table.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        return False

    def supportedDropActions(self):   
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction   # Переместите данные из источника в цель.

    def flags(self, indexRow):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled \
               | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled             


class MyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):  
        if element == self.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop and not option.rect.isNull():
            option_new = QtWidgets.QStyleOption(option)
            option_new.rect.setLeft(0)
            if widget:
                option_new.rect.setRight(widget.width())
            option = option_new
        super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)


class MyTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyle(MyStyle())
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)                      # Выделение строки
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)  
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)                        
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)         # разрешаем события перетаскивания для виджета 
        self.setDragEnabled(True)         # перетаскивание элементов разрешено;
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)  # позиция возможного сброса элемента будет подсвечена
    
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)


class Testing(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('Testing')
        self.btn_add_record = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить запись')
        self.btn_add_record.clicked.connect(self.on_add_record)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setObjectName('widget')

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.table = MyTableView(self)
        self.table.setObjectName('MyTableView')
        
        self.model = MyModel(self.table)
        self.model.setObjectName('MyModel')
        self.model.setTable('datafiles')
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.select()
        # self.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self.updateNumRow)
        self.updateNumRow()

        vbox_main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(vbox_main)
        vbox_main.addWidget(self.btn_add_record)
        vbox_main.addWidget(self.table)
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Drag&Drop Rows in TableView with SqlTableModel')
        self.show()

    def on_add_record(self):
        if self.table.selectionModel().currentIndex().row() == -1:
            self.model.insertRow(0)
        else:
            self.model.insertRow(self.table.selectionModel().currentIndex().row() + 1)

    def updateNumRow(self):
        for i, x in enumerate(range(self.model.rowCount())):
            self.model.setData(self.model.index(i, 1), i)  # + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    database.setDatabaseName(r'TestSQLTable.db')
    database.open()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    test = Testing()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @НикитаСолоницын что не так?